# Flutter decoding JSON simple response without making custom class

Tags: flutter, django-rest-framework

I'm testing out API calls for the first time on flutter web with a backend that isn't firebase(although I'm using it for authentication).
When I test in Postman with the auth token it works fine, but not when I try to call it in the client.

I've done it before by making custom classes, but I will have some very simple things that I don't need a class for. For example, the API I'm trying to retrieve is a simple:

```
{
    "message": "This is your dashboard"
}
```

How do I get the "This is your dashboard" displayed in my UI?

I tried making a simple call like this(which again, the headers worked in Postman):

```
Future<String?> getDashboardInfo() async {
  final firebaseToken = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.getIdToken();

  final response = await dio.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/',
      options: Options(
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer $firebaseToken"
        },

        // responseType: ResponseType.plain)
      ));

  Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.data);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(data['message']);
    return data['message'];
  } else {
    print(response.statusCode);

    // return "error";
  }
  return null;
}
```

But when I do this a page opens called browser_adapter.dart opens and highlights this error:

```
xhr.onError.first.then((_) {
      // Unfortunately, the underlying XMLHttpRequest API doesn't expose any
      // specific information about the error itself.
      completer.completeError(
        DioError(
          type: DioErrorType.response,
          error: 'XMLHttpRequest error.',
          requestOptions: options,
        ),
        StackTrace.current,
      );
    });
```

EDIT:
For some reason when I comment out the Map, the request successfully sends, however whenever I try to get data out of the response I get  new error in browser.adapter.dart

```
xhr.onLoad.first.then((_) {
  Uint8List body = (xhr.response as ByteBuffer).asUint8List();
  completer.complete(
    ResponseBody.fromBytes(
      body,
      xhr.status,
      headers: xhr.responseHeaders.map((k, v) => MapEntry(k, v.split(','))),
      statusMessage: xhr.statusText,
      isRedirect: xhr.status == 302 || xhr.status == 301,
    ),
  );
});
```

Comment: It's likely a CORS error. Is your endpoint at localhost:8000 adding the relevant CORS headers?

Comment: @RichardHeap you were right, I made some progress on it with the CORS stuff and now the backend sees the request, however I'm still getting a weird error with the DIO package and it seems like I'm not the only one https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/961 I think I'll switch over to the classic http package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a few things. I added some of the CORS settings to my server and disabled web security on my chrome.dart file so it works locally on my machine. Additionally, I ended up not making a Map with the future request. In the end after all the other things, the simple call looks like this:

```
Future<String?> getDashboardInfo() async {
  final firebaseToken = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.getIdToken();

  final response = await dio.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/',
      options: Options(method: 'GET', headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer $firebaseToken",
      }, extra: {
        'withCredentials': true,
      }));

  try {
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      throw Exception('Failed to load dashboard');
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.data);
      print('data: ${response.data['message']}');
      return response.data['message'];
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  return null;
}
```